# How to efficiently rename variables using sas

Tags: sas, renaming

I got a SAS dataset `DATA` which contains 100 variables. Unfortunately, this dataset dont contain the name of each variable. It just name the variable as `VAR1` - `Var100`. I got a seperate file which list the name of each variable `Name` (one name per cell). I donot want to rename it one by one so the following code is not an option.

```
data lib.test (rename = (var1= truename1 var2 = truename2 ...) ;
   set lib.test;
run;
```

Following Reeze's suggestions, I try to implement the following solution `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29006915/rename-variable-regardless-of-its-name-in-sas`.

```
proc sql;
   /* Write the individual rename assignments */
   select strip(name) || " = " || substr("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ", varnum , 1)

   /* Store them in a macro variable and separate them by spaces */
   into :vars separated by " "

   /* Use a sas dictionary table to find metadata about the dataset */
   from sashelp.vcolumn
   where libname = "LIB"
     and memname = "TEST"
     and 1 <= varnum <= 100;
quit;

proc datasets lib=lib nolist nodetails;
   modify test;
   rename &vars.;
quit;
```

Now, instead of using a,b,c,d ... to rename my variable, I want to use the name on dataset`Name` as new names. Dataset `Name` looks like the following (I can transpose it if it is easier to use). The order of `Name` is the same as variable sequence in dataset `lib.test`. How can I change the code above to achieve this?

```
Name
name1
anc
sjsjd
mdmd
```

Comment: Create a data set with columns old-name and new-name and use that to generate the rename statement name-pairs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can convert your `NAME` dataset to have both the old and new names and then use that to generate the rename pairs.

```
data name_pairs;
  set name ;
  old_name = cats('VAR',_n_);
run;

proc sql noprint ;
  select catx('=',old_name,name)
    into :vars separated by ' ' 
    from name_pairs
  ;
quit;
```

You can then use the macro variable `VARS` in your rename statement.